# undo/redo command stack for InkCanvas

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls

I am creating paint like application using InkCanvas , I am willing to implement Undo 
and Redo functionality in my application .

Which is the best way to implement Undo / Redo for InkCanvas ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its too late but if someone is here for InkCanvas only than [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e447070-786e-4452-9e3b-dd109972829a/undo-redo-in-wpf-inkcanvas?forum=wpf) might help:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection _added;
    System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollection _removed;
    private bool handle = true;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        inkCanvas1.Strokes.StrokesChanged += Strokes_StrokesChanged;
    }

    private void Strokes_StrokesChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Ink.StrokeCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(handle)
        {
            _added = e.Added;
            _removed = e.Removed;
        }
    }


    private void Undo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        handle = false;
        inkCanvas1.Strokes.Remove(_added);
        inkCanvas1.Strokes.Add(_removed);
        handle = true;
    }

    private void Redo(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        handle = false;
        inkCanvas1.Strokes.Add(_added);
        inkCanvas1.Strokes.Remove(_removed);
        handle = true;
    }
}
```

And in XAML:

```
<InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas1" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Yellow"/>
<Button Content="Undo" Click="Undo" />
<Button Content="Redo" Click="Redo"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented undo / redo for a WPF application and ended up publishing my undo / redo code to http://muf.codeplex.com/. You can also get it via NuGet. Just look for "MUF" or "Monitored Undo Framework". It includes support for Silverlight 4.0, as well as .NET 3.5, 4.0, and WP7.

In my WPF app, we also had an InkCanvas that supported Undo / Redo. In my case, the strokes for the InkCanvas were saved to a database with the rest of the data. I hooked the various events on InkCanvas to detect when the strokes had changed. Then used these events to update the entities.

The entities tracked the changes to the strokes and integrated into the Undo / Redo library. When the user clicked Undo, the library would alter the entities back to their original state. Then I'd push those strokes back into the InkCanvas and trigger a layout update.

Comments and questions are welcome on the codeplex site ( http://muf.codeplex.com/ ). You'll also find complete documentation and sample apps there.

Comment: The library is great! It would be nice if you'd provide its usage for inkcanvas. For example: var undoRoot = UndoService.Current[this.inkCanvas]

Comment: Hell, the MUF is difficult to use. I couldn't get a simple undo/redo code working properly. The codeplex requires more examples, and not as complex as in your Photo app or unit tests. You should provide users the simplest possible sample to get MUF working.

Comment: @VasiliyBorovyak I'd be happy to assist. Feel free to post a question on the codeplex site and I'll continue the discussion there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps.. But one very easy way to **UNDO** is:

**YourWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
 private void Undo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (YourInkCanva.Strokes.Count > 0)
            {
                YourInkCanva.Strokes.RemoveAt(YourInkCanva.Strokes.Count - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                // Else Do Nothing.
            }
        }
```

- You would want to replace `YourInkCanva` with the name of your inkcanva.